# storing an array of dom elements in local storage does not work. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to store an array that holds DOM elemenst into localStorage. I can't append the elements I store in the array when storing/getting it from localStorage. But currently, my program works if I don't use localStorage, and I can append the array elements completely fine. Here's an example I just quickly wrote up which would lead to an error for me when using localStorage. What is the cause for this error?

```
**html**
<div class = "container">
   <div class = "stuff"> Store this text </div>
</div>

<div class = "storeHere">


**index.js**
let arr = [];
if (localStorage.length == 0) localStorage.setItem("arr", JSON.stringify(arr));
else {
   //psuedocode: Calling the imported method in "other.js"
}

**other.js** 
method() {
   let temp = [];
   temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arr"));
   temp.push(document.querySelector(".stuff");
   localStorage.setItem("arr", JSON.stringify(temp));

   const storeHere = document.querySelector(".storeHere");
   
   storeHere.appendChild(temp[0]); //Error, not of type Node



}
```

Comment: you could always store the HTML (innerHTML or outerHTML, depending on your need) to localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Put only serializable values into storage. Elements aren't serializable.

If you want to store `Store this text`, then store *just* that text. If the dynamic values include nested elements, either construct those nested elements when needed, or store the whole HTML string and set the `.innerHTML` of the container.

Here, the child of `.stuff` is only a plain single string, so just put that one string into storage.

```
// store string
localStorage.stuffText = document.querySelector('.stuff').textContent;

// retrieve string and put into DOM
if (localStorage.stuffText) {
  document.querySelector('.stuff').textContent = localStorage.stuffText;
  // or if you want to put it into a .storeHere element, use that selector instead
}
```

If you want to store an array of strings, then maybe something like

```
const storedArr = localStorage.arr ? JSON.parse(localStorage.arr) : [];
// store string
storedArr.push(document.querySelector('.stuff').textContent);
localStorage.stuffText = JSON.stringify(storedArr);

// retrieve string and put into DOM
if (localStorage.arr) {
  const storedArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.arr);
  for (const item of storedArr) {
    document.querySelector('.stuff').textContent = item;
  }
  // or if you want to put it into a .storeHere element, use that selector instead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Element is not serializable, so the localStorage cannot store it. You need to serialize it into string before save it. I recommend using `element.outerHTML` with `JSON.stringify` .

Example code in your case with array:

```
// Serialize
const arr = []
// convert to string
const elementAsString = document.querySelector('div').outerHTML
// add to your current array
arr.push(elementAsString)
// use JSON.stringify to keep correct array format in localStorage
localStorage.setItem('arr', JSON.stringify(arr))


// Deserialize
const saveArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arr'))
// we need create an empty element first
const e = document.createElement('div')
// append element to a parent before set outerHTML
document.body.append(e)
// set HTML for it
e.outerHTML = saveArr[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace these two line and your bugs will fix.

Inside **other.js** `method()` function :-

```
function method () {
 //temp.push(document.querySelector(".stuff"));
 temp.push(document.querySelector(".stuff").outerHTML);

  //storeHere.appendChild(temp[0])
  storeHere.innerHTML += temp[0];
}
```

**Explanation**

1. We cannot stringify a `HTMLNode` ( which is returned by the `document.querySelector`) because it is not a string, but we can get it as a string using its `outerHTML` property.
2. When you push the `HTMLNode` in the `arr` and set it to localStorage as string then `localStorage.getItem("arr")` return **"[ '[object HTMLNode]' ]"** as a string which you parsed as an array. It makes `temp[0] = '[object HTMLNode]'`, which is a string ( not the `HTMLNode` ), which give you the error on **appending** it as a child Node *( that you mentioned in the comment )*.

*I was a bit late in answering because something came up when I was typing the answer*